# How can I find out when TalkBack has finished announcing a ViewPager page change?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, talkback

I am using a ViewPager to show pages in a talking book. Normally, after a page change, the application immediately starts playing the audio for the page. However, with Talkback enabled, changing the page causes it to say something like "page 2 of 10". This is played on top of the audio I am playing of the page content. I would like to prevent that.

I would therefore like some way to find out when TalkBack has finished its announcement so I can wait until then to start playing the page content audio.

It would also be interesting to know how to prevent the TalkBack announcement of the page change, since some users may find that starting to hear the page content gives sufficient information. One way I've found is to override onInitializeAccessibilityEvent in the ViewPager, and if the event type is AccessibilityEventCompat.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED, pass zero to event.setToIndex() and event.setFromIndex(). But this does not seem like a proper way to do it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with a similar situation.

Comment: I didn't find anything better than already indicated in the question, sorry.